# How can set two ' (apostrophe) together in echo

Tags: php, echo

I have this code :

```
echo ' <style> #post_sx {background:url('../images/posts/T_P1.png') right center no-repeat;} </style>';
```

The `‘` character after echo and `‘` character in background url address can't be together I forgot how can solve this?

and when I use :

```
 echo ' <style> #post_sx {background:url("../images/posts/T_P1.png") right center no-repeat;} </style>';
```

Style doesn’t work properly.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using double quotes instead of single quotes for the string allows you to use single quote inside it:

```
echo "string with 'quotes' inside";
```

Comment: Thank you , i try but i can't do that

Comment: So...what's the string you're trying to echo?

Comment: <style> #post_sx {background:url('../images/posts/T_P1.png') right center no-repeat;}</style>

Comment: Then echo "<style> #post_sx {background:url('../images/posts/T_P1.png') right center no-repeat;}</style>" should work.  If it doesn't, give more details about why (your problem might be with the css you generate, not with the process of generation)